# How do I modify a WHERE statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to alter a query that will allow not only the user to receive results by inputing the last name of the particular fighter, but inputing the first name of the fighter. How can I change the query below to accomplish this?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT distinct
'${searchT}' searchalp,
(SELECT COUNT(fighterId) FROM tblFighter where fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%') totalresults,
A.FighterID, 
A.Fighter_FirstName, 
A.Fighter_NickName, 
if (A.Fighter_Height > 0, 
CONCAT(FLOOR(A.Fighter_Height/12), '\' ', MOD(A.Fighter_Height,12), '"'), '')     Fighter_Height_inch, 
A.Fighter_NormalWeight, 
if (A.Fighter_Reach > 0, CONCAT(ROUND(A.Fighter_Reach,0), '"') , '') Fighter_Reach, 
A.Fighter_Stance,
CONCAT('/fighter/',REPLACE(REPLACE(LCASE(A.Fighter_FirstName),'  ','-'),'.',''),'/',REPLACE(LCASE(A.Fighter_LastName),' ','-'),'/',A.FighterID,'/')  fighterURL,
(select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 1) fighterCareerWins, (select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 2) fighterCareerLosses, (select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 3) fighterCareerDraws,
fighter_lastName, FA.AccoladeDescription FROM tblFighter as A LEFT JOIN (SELECT FighterId, AccoladeDescription, AccoladeType
  FROM tblAccolade 
  JOIN tblEvent USING(EventID)
  JOIN (SELECT AccoladeID, Max(Event_Date) as MaxAccDate 
          FROM tblAccolade 
          JOIN tblEvent ON tblAccolade.EventID = tblEvent.EventID  
         WHERE AccoladeType = 'Belt' AND AccoladeDescription not like 'WEC%'
        GROUP BY AccoladeID) as tmpMaxAccDate ON tblAccolade.AccoladeID = tmpMaxAccDate.AccoladeID 


 WHERE Event_Date = MaxAccDate) as FA ON FA.FighterId = A.FighterId and FA.AccoladeType = 'Belt'  where A.fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' order by A.fighter_lastName ASC LIMIT ${stInd}, ${lstInd}
```

Comment: `impute` - a statement attributing something dishonest (especially a criminal offense); did you mean `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `where A.fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' and A.fighter_firstName like '${searchU}%'` ought to do it.  If one or other of the strings is empty then the search will be solely based on the other string.

Comment: That did not work. I tried using 
    where A.fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' or A.fighter_firstName like '${searchU}%'

That did not work either

Comment: If you want the user to enter a single string e.g. James and have it return Burt Jameson and James Burtfield (those well known fighters!) then change it to an OR as you have and change the searchU to searchT instead - so the same parameter is used in two places.

Comment: @Mojaray2k - no problem, glad to be of assistance.